# Successfully posting html encoded and including a pound sign to a VB.net method

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, decode, urlencode

I am posting a form which sends an email, the HTML for part of the email body is created and posted by jQuery and an AJAX post method to a web method in ASP.net using VB.

Here's a snippet

```
var tbl = $('<table/>');
var paymentCell = $('<td/>').html('&#163;' + thisAmount).appendTo(row);
$(row).appendTo(tbl); 
     // Generates the element in question
```

This, amongst other things are then posted as a data variable by AJAX, the data variable looks something like this:

```
 var data = '{ "emailHtml":"' + escape((wrap).html()) + '"}';
```

This is then decoded on the server side like this:

```
emailHtml = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(emailHtml)
```

This all works fine except for pound signs, which are not decoded properly. I have tried using `&#163;` as per above, and `&pound;` to display the HTML characters but I am always getting a weird `?` symbol returned in the html decoded at the server end... is there a way round this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the `escape()` call, as jQuery allows for built-in encoding, so I think your value is being double-encoded.

Make sure you are using `UTF-8` as your encoding and charset in your application, like this:

web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
</system.web>
```

HTML pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Without escape it simply won't post as it then creates an invalid JSON post object due to HTML tags, and quote marks etc.
I'll try the encoding tag suggestion

Comment: Update - nope, however, I had a thought, the HTML is being sent in an email and it is in the received email that this problem is occurring, perhaps I need to explicitly set the character type in the headers of the email document?